# Issue with Java class loader

Tags: java

I compile a class successfully like this:

```
zookeeper@zookeeper-virtual-machine:~/zookeeper-3.4.5$ javac -cp "zookeeper-3.4.5.jar" org/zookeeper/Worker.java
```

But when I then try to run it Java's class loader can't find the class:

```
zookeeper@zookeeper-virtual-machine:~/zookeeper-3.4.5$ java -cp "zookeeper-3.4.5.jar" org.zookeeper.Worker
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/zookeeper/Worker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zookeeper.Worker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.zookeeper.Worker. Program will exit.
```

Here are the relevant parts of Worker.java

```
package org.zookeeper;
...

class Worker implements Watcher {

...

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Worker worker = new Worker(args[0], args[1],args[2]);
        worker.processRequest();
    }
```

Why can't the class loader load the class?

Comment: Does `zookeeper-3.4.5.jar` actually contain the class?

Comment: @Reimeus no. I wrote the worker class and store/compile it in org/zookeeper. But the Worker class depends on things in zookeeper-3.4.5.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `-cp` flag is specified, the current directory is not automatically used in the classpath so needs to be added explicitly:

```
java -cp zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:. org.zookeeper.Worker
```

Answer (score 0):

Why quote the jar anyway?

In any case, you still need *your* classes on the classpath, e.g.,

```
java -cp .:zookeeper-3.4.5.jar org.zookeeper.Worker
```

Comment: I quote the jar because worker depends on classes in the jar to run and java needs to find them. Correct?

Comment: @abe3 That's why you *need* the jar, I asked why you *quoted* the jar.

Comment: I guess I am in the habit of putting class paths in quotes. I take it that is not nevessary?

Comment: @abe3 Rarely; if a path has a space in it then you can use quotes or just escape the space. There aren't any other dependencies required for zookeeper, though? Classpath management is often (usually) better handled by stuff like Maven etc.

Comment: there are -- but I added them into the classpath after resolving this issue. Tx for tips.